# How to read additional data posted by form in django forms.py

Tags: django

I'm trying to write kind off bussiness mail management.

In simple world, it'll have bunch of mail templates that will use un mailmerge operation

There will be 2 kind of user:

1. those who create mail templates, let's call them 'tc' (template creator)
2. thoise who will issueing mails by term of triggering a mail merge.

In this post I will only ask about the tc part.
The work sequnce will :

1. TC make a MS docx,
2. upload to this web app
3. web app will get all variable names from docx ( I use docxtpl library), and save it on MailTemplate model class.

here is my MailTemplate model class

```
class MailTemplate(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  tfile = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/mailtemplate', null=True, blank=True)
  schema = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
  # conto: ['{"name": "kepada", "label": "Kepada", "type": 2, "format": ""}']
  def __str__(self) -> str:
    return self.name
```

all variables gathered by docxtpl, is combined in the form as list-of-dicts and saved in MailTemplate.schema

example:

```
[{"name": "date", "label": null, "type": 2, "format": ""}, {"name": "invoiceNumber", "label": null, "type": 2, "format": ""}, {"name": "company", "label": null, "type": 2, "format": ""}, {"name": "total", "label": null, "type": 2, "format": ""}]
```

When TC first update new template, MailTemplate.schema is still empty.
I make ModelAdmin to use custom change_view template.

```
class MailTemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  change_form_template = 'mailtemplate_form.html'
  form = MailTemplateForm
```

and here is the mailtemplate_form.html

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block after_field_sets %}

  <!--- add htmx -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.6.0"></script>

  <style>
    /* DivTable.com */
    .divTable{
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .divTableRow {
      display: table-row;
    }
    .divTableCell, .divTableHead {
      border: 1px solid #999999;
      display: table-cell;
      padding: 3px 10px;
    }
    .divTableHeading {
      display: table-header-group;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .divTableFoot {
      background-color: #EEE;
      display: table-footer-group;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .divTableBody {
      display: table-row-group;
    }
  </style>

  <style>
    .button.bino_btn {
      background:none; border:none;
    }
  </style>

  {% if not add %}
    <div id="schema_head" hx-get="{% url 'get_schema' object_id %}" hx-trigger="load" hx-target="#alldata" hx-swap="innerHTML">
      <b>Schema  </b>
      <button class="button.bino_btn" hx-get="{% url 'get_schema' object_id %}" hx-trigger="click" hx-target="#alldata" hx-swap="innerHTML">Refresh</button>
    </div>
    <div id="table_for_schema" class="divTable">
      <div class="divTableHeading">
        <div class="divTableRow">
          <div class="divTableHead">Nama Variabel</div>
          <div class="divTableHead">Label</div>
          <div class="divTableHead">Tipe</div>
          <div class="divTableHead">Format</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="alldata" class="divTableBody">
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

when that template called in 'change' mode, it will call a views function that will read respective MailTemplate.schema, deserialized it and add additional fields inside form.

Here is resulted HTML form (copied from 'inspector') :

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-us"><head>
<title>docx01 | Change mail template | Django site admin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/admin/css/base.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/admin/css/dark_mode.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css">
  <script src="/static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js" defer=""></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/admin/css/forms.css">


<script src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script src="/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script src="/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
<script src="/static/admin/js/actions.js"></script>
<script src="/static/admin/js/urlify.js"></script>
<script src="/static/admin/js/prepopulate.js"></script>
<script src="/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.js"></script>


    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/admin/css/responsive.css">
    

<meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
<style>                      .htmx-indicator{opacity:0;transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;}                      .htmx-request .htmx-indicator{opacity:1}                      .htmx-request.htmx-indicator{opacity:1}                    </style></head>

<body class=" app-myapp model-mailtemplate change-form" data-admin-utc-offset="0">

<!-- Container -->
<div id="container">

    
    <!-- Header -->
    
    <div id="header">
        <div id="branding">
        
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="/admin/">Django administration</a></h1>

        </div>
        
        
        <div id="user-tools">
            
                Welcome,
                <strong>admin</strong>.
            
            
                
                    <a href="/">View site</a> /
                
                
                    
                    
                
                
                <a href="/admin/password_change/">Change password</a> /
                
                <form id="logout-form" method="post" action="/admin/logout/">
                    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="ZBziDfqR44MaX5oT5fyG9cRUkO1uqi70JZjLQB1gzdHWHaL2l7gNYJH0HnLaMWtp">
                    <button type="submit">Log out</button>
                </form>
            
        </div>
        
        
        
    </div>
    
    <!-- END Header -->
    
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<a href="/admin/">Home</a>
› <a href="/admin/myapp/">Myapp</a>
› <a href="/admin/myapp/mailtemplate/">Mail templates</a>
› docx01
</div>

    

    <div class="main shifted" id="main">
      
        
          
<button class="sticky toggle-nav-sidebar" id="toggle-nav-sidebar" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
<nav class="sticky" id="nav-sidebar">
  <input type="search" id="nav-filter" placeholder="Start typing to filter…" aria-label="Filter navigation items">
  


  
    <div class="app-auth module">
      <table>
        <caption>
          <a href="/admin/auth/" class="section" title="Models in the Authentication and Authorization application">Authentication and Authorization</a>
        </caption>
        
          <tbody><tr class="model-group">
            
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/auth/group/">Groups</a></th>
            

            
              <td><a href="/admin/auth/group/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
            

            
          </tr>
        
          <tr class="model-user">
            
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/auth/user/">Users</a></th>
            

            
              <td><a href="/admin/auth/user/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
            

            
          </tr>
        
      </tbody></table>
    </div>
  
    <div class="app-myapp module current-app">
      <table>
        <caption>
          <a href="/admin/myapp/" class="section" title="Models in the Myapp application">Myapp</a>
        </caption>
        
          <tbody><tr class="model-mailtemplate current-model">
            
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/myapp/mailtemplate/" aria-current="page">Mail templates</a></th>
            

            
              <td><a href="/admin/myapp/mailtemplate/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
            

            
          </tr>
        
      </tbody></table>
    </div>
  


</nav>

        
      
      <div class="content">
        
          
        
        <!-- Content -->
        <div id="content" class="colM">
          
          <h1>Change mail template</h1>
          <h2>docx01</h2>
          <div id="content-main">


  <ul class="object-tools">
    
      

<li>
    
    <a href="/admin/myapp/mailtemplate/7/history/" class="historylink">History</a>
</li>



    
  </ul>


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="mailtemplate_form" novalidate=""><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="ZBziDfqR44MaX5oT5fyG9cRUkO1uqi70JZjLQB1gzdHWHaL2l7gNYJH0HnLaMWtp">
<div>







  <fieldset class="module aligned ">
    
    
    
        <div class="form-row field-name">
            
            
                <div>
                    
                    
                        <label class="required" for="id_name">Name:</label>
                        
                            <input type="text" name="name" value="docx01" class="vTextField" maxlength="20" required="" id="id_name">
                        
                    
                    
                </div>
            
        </div>
    
        <div class="form-row field-tfile">
            
            
                <div>
                    
                    
                        <label for="id_tfile">Tfile:</label>
                        
                            <p class="file-upload">Currently: <a href="/uploads/mailtemplate/invoice-template_BCpUuSw.docx">uploads/mailtemplate/invoice-template_BCpUuSw.docx</a>
<span class="clearable-file-input">
<input type="checkbox" name="tfile-clear" id="tfile-clear_id">
<label for="tfile-clear_id">Clear</label></span><br>
Change:
<input type="file" name="tfile" id="id_tfile"></p>
                        
                    
                    
                </div>
            
        </div>
    
</fieldset>






  <!--- add htmx -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.6.0"></script>

  <style>
    /* DivTable.com */
    .divTable{
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .divTableRow {
      display: table-row;
    }
    .divTableCell, .divTableHead {
      border: 1px solid #999999;
      display: table-cell;
      padding: 3px 10px;
    }
    .divTableHeading {
      display: table-header-group;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .divTableFoot {
      background-color: #EEE;
      display: table-footer-group;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .divTableBody {
      display: table-row-group;
    }
  </style>

  <style>
    .button.bino_btn {
      background:none; border:none;
    }
  </style>

  
    <div id="schema_head" hx-get="/mst/htmx/get_schema/7" hx-trigger="load" hx-target="#alldata" hx-swap="innerHTML" class="">
      <b>Schema  </b>
      <button class="button.bino_btn" hx-get="/mst/htmx/get_schema/7" hx-trigger="click" hx-target="#alldata" hx-swap="innerHTML">Refresh</button>
    </div>
    <div id="table_for_schema" class="divTable">
      <div class="divTableHeading">
        <div class="divTableRow">
          <div class="divTableHead">Nama Variabel</div>
          <div class="divTableHead">Label</div>
          <div class="divTableHead">Tipe</div>
          <div class="divTableHead">Format</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="alldata" class="divTableBody"><div id="31d6fa45-e660-4983-bfcb-f5217fd26e16" class="divTableRow">
  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="hidden" name="varname_31d6fa45-e660-4983-bfcb-f5217fd26e16" value="date">
    date
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="text" name="varlabel_31d6fa45-e660-4983-bfcb-f5217fd26e16" value="None" class="vTextField" maxlength="20">
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <select name="vartype_31d6fa45-e660-4983-bfcb-f5217fd26e16">
      
        <option value="1">
      
      Integer</option>

      
        <option value="2" selected="">
      
      String</option>

      
        <option value="3">
      
      Date</option>

    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="text" name="varformat_31d6fa45-e660-4983-bfcb-f5217fd26e16" class="vTextField" maxlength="20">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="0bffd751-79a3-4561-b62f-dc254e2bbaac" class="divTableRow">
  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="hidden" name="varname_0bffd751-79a3-4561-b62f-dc254e2bbaac" value="invoiceNumber">
    invoiceNumber
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="text" name="varlabel_0bffd751-79a3-4561-b62f-dc254e2bbaac" value="None" class="vTextField" maxlength="20">
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <select name="vartype_0bffd751-79a3-4561-b62f-dc254e2bbaac">
      
        <option value="1">
      
      Integer</option>

      
        <option value="2" selected="">
      
      String</option>

      
        <option value="3">
      
      Date</option>

    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="text" name="varformat_0bffd751-79a3-4561-b62f-dc254e2bbaac" class="vTextField" maxlength="20">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cc528860-3855-4645-bd3f-948e297bda76" class="divTableRow">
  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="hidden" name="varname_cc528860-3855-4645-bd3f-948e297bda76" value="company">
    company
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="text" name="varlabel_cc528860-3855-4645-bd3f-948e297bda76" value="None" class="vTextField" maxlength="20">
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <select name="vartype_cc528860-3855-4645-bd3f-948e297bda76">
      
        <option value="1">
      
      Integer</option>

      
        <option value="2" selected="">
      
      String</option>

      
        <option value="3">
      
      Date</option>

    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="text" name="varformat_cc528860-3855-4645-bd3f-948e297bda76" class="vTextField" maxlength="20">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="66971274-8d70-4766-8254-996bda8991b0" class="divTableRow">
  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="hidden" name="varname_66971274-8d70-4766-8254-996bda8991b0" value="total">
    total
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="text" name="varlabel_66971274-8d70-4766-8254-996bda8991b0" value="None" class="vTextField" maxlength="20">
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <select name="vartype_66971274-8d70-4766-8254-996bda8991b0">
      
        <option value="1">
      
      Integer</option>

      
        <option value="2" selected="">
      
      String</option>

      
        <option value="3">
      
      Date</option>

    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="text" name="varformat_66971274-8d70-4766-8254-996bda8991b0" class="vTextField" maxlength="20">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="01ed7377-b526-4acf-a556-b87a1012091f" class="divTableRow">
  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="hidden" name="varname_01ed7377-b526-4acf-a556-b87a1012091f" value="items">
    items
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="text" name="varlabel_01ed7377-b526-4acf-a556-b87a1012091f" value="None" class="vTextField" maxlength="20">
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <select name="vartype_01ed7377-b526-4acf-a556-b87a1012091f">
      
        <option value="1">
      
      Integer</option>

      
        <option value="2" selected="">
      
      String</option>

      
        <option value="3">
      
      Date</option>

    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="text" name="varformat_01ed7377-b526-4acf-a556-b87a1012091f" class="vTextField" maxlength="20">
  </div>
</div>

</div>
      <!--div id="alldata" hx-get="/mst/htmx/get_schema/7" hx-trigger="load" hx-swap="beforeend" class="divTableBody">
      </div-->
    </div>
  









<div class="submit-row">

<input type="submit" value="Save" class="default" name="_save">

    
    <p class="deletelink-box"><a href="/admin/myapp/mailtemplate/7/delete/" class="deletelink">Delete</a></p>


<input type="submit" value="Save and add another" name="_addanother">
<input type="submit" value="Save and continue editing" name="_continue">


</div>



    <script id="django-admin-form-add-constants" src="/static/admin/js/change_form.js" async="">
    </script>




<script id="django-admin-prepopulated-fields-constants" src="/static/admin/js/prepopulate_init.js" data-prepopulated-fields="[]">
</script>


</div>
</form></div>

          
          <br class="clear">
        </div>
        <!-- END Content -->
        <div id="footer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END Container -->


</body></html>
```

it's clear that all additional field is between form tags.

And here is my MailTemplateForm class

```
class MailTemplateForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    print(f'Cleaned Data:\n{cleaned_data}\n-------')
  class Meta:
    model = MailTemplate
    fields = '__all__'
```

see that currently for all additional fields I only want to debug print it .

When I edit one of additional field and do save, I only got

```
Cleaned Data:
{'name': 'docx01', 'tfile': <FieldFile: uploads/mailtemplate/invoice-template_BCpUuSw.docx>}
-------
[16/Jan/2023 05:11:35] "POST /admin/myapp/mailtemplate/7/change/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[16/Jan/2023 05:11:35] "GET /admin/myapp/mailtemplate/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6823
[16/Jan/2023 05:11:35] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3141
```

So, my question is:
How to read all the additional data in forms.py?
Kindly please give me any clue.

Sincerely
bino

Comment: If you don't specify your fields in your form code, `form.cleaned_data` won't contain the extra fields. You can find them in `form.data`, but it seems kind of weird to use that. My suggestion is to add fields in the `__init__` method of your form, not via JS.

Comment: @vinkomlacic thankyou for your suggestion. Actually I never play with form's __init_ method before. I'll try to find docs about it and how to got list of dynamic field.